# How to correlate value for new line value

Tags: jmeter, correlation

I am trying to correlate below values but not able to do it.

I have searched below regex in regex tester but it is not working.

**Value:1:**

```
this.setRequestHeader("tempSpecId", "737896904057736821");
```

tried `regex:this.setRequestHeader(\s+"tempSpecId",\s+"([^"]+)"\s*)`

**value:2:**

```
var tririgaSecurity = new TririgaSecurity("NDBkZTEyYzQxMDVl","HzrbV1mi-KKloFirhlE91LHiTV-s4M_A");
```

Here both the values are changing and not able to find it in regex tester with below:

`"tririgasecuritytokeninput", "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Please let me know how to handle these values.

you're help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using regular expressions with round braces, they become a pattern group. A simpler solution would be to use this regex for value 1

```
(\s*"tempSpecId",\s*")(\d*)
```

and the template would be **$2$** along with the match No set to **1**

[image]

For value 2, use the following regular expression

```
TririgaSecurity[(]"([\w]*)","(.*)"
```

for the first value which is 'NDBkZTEyYzQxMDVl', can be obtained from the 1st pattern group i.e by using the template **$1$** and the match No set to **1**

[image]

the second value which is 'HzrbV1mi-KKloFirhlE91LHiTV-s4M_A' can be obtained from the second pattern group of the regex result i.e. the template **$2$** and the match No set to **1**

[image]

Here is the response in the Debug Postprocessor, for the same regular expressions and the pattern groups

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for your reply.i tried these regex in regex tester before applying actual post processor but i am getting match count =0 as out put.

Comment: Hey Manish ,it is working for first value,thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Manish , correlation for tempspecid is working ,but regular expression for second value is not working.

Comment: Hi Kawita, I tried and the regular expressions are working fine. Here is the screenshot. Please make sure there are whitespaces in the regular expressions, when you copy and paste. I have added the screenshot of the response from the debug postprocessor in my answer.

Comment: yes Manish it is working , i have one more doubt X-GWT-Permutation this type of thing is coming in request and it is changing for each recording , not getting in regexp or any response. do you have any idea what is about it

Comment: A lot of this could be specific to the application. Is there some snippet or the script itself that you can share? Also, can you please vote my answer, will be helpful. Thanks !!

Comment: Hi Manish , i am not able to vote up for this Answer, could you please inbox me you're contact details if possible on stack overflow. i have many doubts and not getting resolved.

Comment: i have tried to handle OWASP_CSRFTOKEN token but not able to find exact changed value in respone. 1.i have change it first time and pass to the request 2.again handle second value with same boundary 3.third time value is getting in request but when i am checking in view result tree response contain chnaged value from second value correlation .4. without chnage in response value how to handle this request ,also let me now how can i share jmx , if you have skype id please inbox me ,so that i can share the script.

Comment: You can click on the UP Arrow indicator against my answer to vote for it. Thanks